# Ошибка десериализации JSON

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Всем привет.
Помогите, пожалуйста поборать проблему:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize the current JSON array 
(e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ActionResult`1[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[APRF.HelpService.ApiContract.Models.Responses.GeneralReportResponse]]' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List<T> that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.
Path '', line 1, position 1.
```

Имеется 2 сервиса.

1. Общий рабочий сервис
2. Сервис с отчетами

Чтобы не копировать сервис с отчетами в рабочий сервис. В Сервисе с отчетами была добавлена API, и упакована в пакет.

Пакет добавлен в общий сервис. И через API в пакете этот сервис получает данные отчетов от сервиса отчетов.

Так как API подключается через пакет, то пройтись дебагом и посмотреть что не так не получается.

Так выглядит сам запрос

```
 public static async Task<TResponse> MakePostAsync<TResponse>(this HttpClient client, string relativeUrl, string token, object request = null, Func<HttpResponseMessage, Task<TResponse>> onResponse = null)
    {
        string url = UrlHelper.Combine(client.BaseAddress!.ToString(), relativeUrl);
        string content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request);
        HttpRequestMessage httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
        {
            httpRequestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
        }

        httpRequestMessage.Content = new StringContent(content, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        using HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage);
        if (onResponse != null)
        {
            TResponse val = await onResponse(response);
            if (val != null)
            {
                return val;
            }
        }

        await CheckBadRequest(url, response);
        byte[] bytes = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
        if (typeof(TResponse) == typeof(string))
        {
            return (TResponse)(object)Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
        }

        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TResponse>(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes));
    }
```

Данные приходят в таком виде (напрямую получил их у сервиса отчетов через постман)

```
[
{
    "id": "91244a5e-ea9d-4963-85dd-d39586b070bd",
    "date": "2023-04-06T12:55:44.580277Z",
    "callTime": "00:00:00",
    "phoneNumber": null,
    "number": "A26-1T",
    "operator": "Nosova Юлия",
    "aon": null,
    "phone": "+7 (104)",
    "mobile": null,
    "fax": "+7 (105)",
    "zip": "0000",
    "region": "",
    "rayon": "",
    "fullAddress": " ",
    "annotation": null,
},
{
    "id": "91244a5e-ea9d-4963-85dd-d39586b070bd",
    "date": "2023-04-06T13:01:34.383602Z",
    "callTime": "00:00:00",
    "phoneNumber": null,
    "number": "A26-2T",
    "operator": "Nosova Юлия",
    "aon": null,
    "phone": "+7 (104)",
    "mobile": null,
    "fax": "+7 (105)",
    "zip": "0000",
    "region": "",
    "rayon": "",
    "fullAddress": " ",
    "annotation": null,
} ]
```

Не понятно что не так с JSON
Модели вроде как и в сервисе отчетов и в рабочем сервисе идентичны

Вроде в тексте ошибки есть рекомендация по исправлению, но все равно ничего не понятно
На сколько я понимаю текст ошибки - приходит массив JSON, а принимаемый тип не массив.
Хотя по коду у меня стоит List

```
  async Task<ActionResult<List<GeneralReportResponse>>> IReportApiClient.GetGeneralReportAsync(GetGeneralReportApiRequest vm, string token)
    {
        return await HttpClient.MakePostAsync<ActionResult<List<GeneralReportResponse>>>("api/Report/GetGeneralReport", token, vm);
    }
```

Comment: Вместо `MakePostAsync<ActionResult<List<GeneralReportResponse>>>` должно быть `MakePostAsync<List<GeneralReportResponse>>` и соответственно `async Task<List<GeneralReportResponse>> IReportApiClient...(...)`